# Custom layout for my Game over dialog

Tags: android, android-custom-view, customdialog

I want to create a custom dialog (i cant post image now):

basically it has a GameOver text, scaled edges and two buttons and actual score and coins. How can I make something like this ? I have searched over the forums but didn't find something that is exactly for me.

Comment: There's a hundred ways of making a layout that fits what you explained, so yeah posting an image would be better if you want a proper help. What problem do you face when you create your layout? You can post what you already did and what doesn't work for you, it will be easier

Comment: I just looked over this site for solutions but neither one seemed understandable for me. Maybe I should learn code better.